# Java (Android) : List with multiples types (String; Integer; Integer)

Tags: java, string, list, types, element

As you can see on the title, I would like a list where I can store multiples types. Something like:

```
List <String, Integer, Integer> myList;

myList.add("something", 1337, 123);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `List<Object>`. Done. On a serious note, though. `Integer, Integer>` doesn't make sense.

Comment: You could use a class which holds the data...

Comment: @cricket_007 
My code :
    `List<Object> myList;
    myList.add("test", 1);`

It says "variable 'myList' might not been initialized".
And I'm new at java...

Comment: It would be better to create a custom type and make a `List` of that type. What are these three elements for?

Comment: That code will throw a NullPointerException. You have to make a `new ArrayList<Object>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than a `List<Object>`, you can't add multiple non-related types to a `Collection<?>`. Plus, `myList.add("something", 1337, 123);` is not valid syntax.

I imagine you are loading some Android Adapter, so I would recommend creating a class that you can wrap your data inside of.

```
public class StringIntInt {
    String s;
    int i1, i2;

    public StringIntInt(String s, int i1, int i2) {
        this.s = s;
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
List<StringIntInt> myList = new ArrayList<StringIntInt>();
myList.add(new StringIntInt("something", 123, 1337);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much ♥

Comment: As a follow-up, I assumed you were trying to do [Using a custom ArrayAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

Answer (score 0):

```
 class myClass   
   {
      public String myString;
      public Int numb1;
      public Int numb2;
   }
```

...

```
List<myClass> TheList = new List<myClass>;
```

You could define a struct or class that holds your info, then make a List

Answer (score 0):

> I would like a list where I can store multiples types

The most simple way is this:

```
List <Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add("Stringa");
        list.add(5);
```

The problem is if you need to manipulate them, you should pay very attention:

```
        if(list.get(0) instanceof String){
            System.out.println(list.get(0));
        }
        else if(list.get(0) instanceof Integer){
            list.set(0, (Integer)list.get(0)+10);
        }
```

But reading here:

```
List <String, Integer, Integer> myList;
```

maybe you need some class to use as a tuple:

```
public class Trio{
    String string;
    int value1;
    int value2;

    public Trio(String string, int value1, int value2) {
        this.string = string;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

And then use this:

```
List<Trio> list = new ArrayList<Trio>();
list.add(new Trio("String", 1, 2);
```